# Why did my answer being deleted cost 25 points?

Tags: support, reputation, deleted-answers

My Stack Overflow answer had one upvote and one downvote (and was accepted as the One True Answer), so I would expect to lose 23 points if the answer were deleted. However, [I lost 25 points](https://stackoverflow.com/users/198536/wallyk?tab=reputation) for the deletion. Why?

[image: screenshot of point history]

Comment: Can you add a screenshot? We (non-moderators) can't see deleted posts on your reputation history

Comment: Was it the accepted answer?  That's another 15 points.

Comment: @Servy:  It was the accepted answer.  I have added the screenshot.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Because it also had the accepted checkmark, which disappears when the answer gets deleted.

The easiest way to find that out is to [look at the post timeline](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/1774559/timeline) and see that the last accept event was on your answer.

Comment: Even so, wouldn't that still mean that the question was worth 23 rep, not 25?

Comment: @StephenTG That's what the deletion event says... Originally he has +1 +accept for 25, then he got a downvote for -2, then the post was removed and removed the 23 that was left. There's no problem here.

Comment: @animuson The problem is that the OP said he lost 25 points, not 23 points.  He should have lost just 23 points.

Comment: Ok. I couldn't see the deletion event, so I assumed it said -25, as the question implies

Comment: @Servy In his reputation history I see -23 on the removal event and a -2 for a downvote.

Comment: @animuson Not being mods, we can't see that information on another's profile; we're forced to live with the information the OP included in his question here, and he said 25 (meaning he's clearly mistaken, but we can't prove that, only you can).

Comment: @Servy:  Maybe I am misreading the history, but it looks like I lost 25 points.

Comment: @wallyk You did lose 25 points, but 2 were from a downvote, and 23 were from the deletion, so *the deletion* only removed *23* points.

Comment: @wallyk I think you're confused by the downvote. That downvote was *just cast* about 30 minutes before the post was deleted. So before the deletion occurred, you had gained 25 reputation and lost 2, for a net gain of 23 that had to be reversed with the deletion. If the downvote had occurred, say, 7 days ago, then that -2 event wouldn't be there and you'd only see the -23 for today.

Comment: @animuson:  I see that I got 10 points for another question.  And I am guessing that `-15` beside `today` means that I lost a total of 15 so far today.  So doesn't that mean that the question being deleted cost 25 points?  Total for the question?

Comment: @wallyk Yes, *today* your net loss for that question is -25, but that *doesn't* mean the deletion itself caused a loss of 25. The downvote and deletion are *separate* events. Continuing my example, if that downvote had occurred 7 days ago, your net loss for today would only be -13 rather than -15.

Answer (score 9):

Your rep log indicates that you lost 23 point for the deletion, not 25. The other 2 lost rep are from the downvote.

We can tabulate this out by summing the answer's pre-deletion reputation events:

```
+10 upvote
+15 accept
- 2 downvote
------------
+23 pre-deletion worth
```

When the answer was deleted, you lost the total value of the question's reputational worth to you, which was 23 rep.

To put it another way:

- Suppose I gave you 25 dollars.
- The next day, I need money to buy my lunch, so I say, "Sorry, can I just get 2 of those dollars back from you?"
- The day thereafter, I realize I meant to give those 25 dollars to someone else entirely, so I say, "Terribly sorry, but please give **all** of that money back. That shouldn't have gone to you at all."

When I take back the money, I'm certainly not going to ask for the full $25 back, because you already gave me $2 of it the day before. Thus, on the final day, you give me $23, but your net loss (counting from the first day) was $25, including the other $2.

Answer (score 0):

- 1 Upvote = +10
- 1 Downvote = -2
- 1 Accepted Answer = +15

When you add the upvote and the accepted answer, you get +25.
When you subtract the downvote, you get +23
When your accepted answer gets deleted, it cancels out the net gain you've achieved.  Therefore, it shows up as -23.  If you had 2 downvotes, it would have shown up as -21.  See?